# Dataframe dimension check created by pandas and how to remove the column created by group_by function?

Tags: python, pandas

1. I don't know why the data frame shows that it is 1ROW*30Columes but if I use np.shape to check the data frame, the shape returns (2,31). Can someone help me out?
2. How can I remove the first column in the data frame (1 in the data frame instead of mean radius)

```
import sklearn.datasets
bc = sklearn.datasets.load_breast_cancer(return_X_y = False, as_frame = True)
sk_df = pd.DataFrame(bc.data)   
print(bc.target)            
bc_df=sk_df.assign(CLASS=bc.target)
bc_df
bcmeans_df=bc_df.groupby("CLASS",as_index=False).mean().diff()
bcmeans_df.dropna().drop(bcmeans_df.columns[[0]], axis=1)
np.ndim(bcmeans_df)
```

Comment: `DataFrame.drop` removes rows or columns by label

Comment: Numpy doesn't inherently know anything about pandas, so it's probably counting the row and column indexes as elements in each dimension. `df.shape` is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After running your code, `bcmeans_df.shape` is `(2,31)` because the changes in the following line are lost (not assigned to a variable):

```
bcmeans_df.dropna().drop(bcmeans_df.columns[[0]], axis=1)
```

Is this what you meant?

```
bcmeans_df = bcmeans_df.dropna().drop(bcmeans_df.columns[[0]], axis=1)
```

This gives `bcmeans_df.shape == (1, 30)`

Here's another way to get the differences in the means:

```
bc = sklearn.datasets.load_breast_cancer(return_X_y=False, as_frame=True)
bc_df = pd.concat([bc.data, bc.target], axis=1)
bc_diffmeans = bc_df.groupby("target").mean().diff().iloc[1].rename('diffmeans')
assert(bc_diffmeans.shape == (30,))
```